# Are there any high profile commercial users of GIT?

Tags: git

I'd like to introduce GIT into my organization, and it would help if I could point to some high profile commercial users of it.  I know I could point at Mozilla, Linux kernel, etc, but I'm looking for non-open source users.

Comment: Related, but not duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/410393/is-git-ready-to-be-recommended-to-my-boss

Comment: Do you want to introduce it because you don't have meaningful version control or as a replacement for an existing system. If the former then you sell version control and oh by the way here's one that should works well in our environment, if the latter then its a far more interesting question (-:

Comment: Mozilla uses **Mercurial**, not Git, if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Have you been to [GitHub](http://github.com/) recently? The list is too long to post here and would quickly become stale.

Answer (score 1):

[Google uses it](http://source.android.com/download) for developing the Android platform. However, it's technically an open-source project.

This site has a good [list of projects that use git](http://git.or.cz/gitwiki/GitProjects) and don't forget to [check Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_%28software%29#Projects_using_Git). However, many  of the listed are open source. You might be able to find some that aren't though.

Digg [uses git](http://blog.digg.com/?p=900) too.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know about high profiles and my company does not qualify as it yet but the strategy that worked quite well for me is simply to give it a try and see what happens :)
I work on a small team of three developers so it was easier for me, it was a bit difficult at first but now everyone pretty happy about it.

The only real problem is the gui, people will argue that command line is enough but it is not and having a good interface to quickly spot differences and choose what to commit and not greatly help if not mandatory, in my case we work on macbook's and the gui is GitX but I don't think there is a real alternative under windows.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Subversion for a while. Its enough to make people want to switch to using git forever. Especially merging branches involving major changes. Really painful...